# How to update row in CursorAdapter properly

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a trouble with my CursorAdapter data updating.
When I press on the "star" img of listview row item i needs to get changes in DB column "isFav" (0 to 1 and vice versa) and show completed star or free star(favorite checkbox e.g.).
But when I pressing on the star - current row star is not updating, but last of showed rows get affected, like as I press on it. Screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/2eph8uf/5

The following code is placing below:

```
private class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;


public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
}

News tmp = new News(0,0,null,null,0,0);

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    tmp.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHelper.NAME)));
    tmp.setDescr(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHelper.DESCRIPTION)));
    tmp.setPubdate(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHelper.DATE)));
    tmp.setGuid(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHelper.UID)));
    tmp.setIsFav(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHelper.IS_FAV)));
    tmp.setIsRead(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dbHelper.IS_READ)));

    TextView title_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    if (title_text != null) {
        title_text.setText(tmp.getName() + " " + convertLongToDate(tmp.getPubdate()));
    }

    title_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent _intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemActivity.class);
            _intent.putExtra("title", tmp.getName() + " " + Long.toString(tmp.getPubdate()));
            _intent.putExtra("desc", tmp.getDescr());
            startActivity(_intent);
            if (tmp.getIsRead() == 1)
                return;

            tmp.setIsRead(1);
            //working wrong!
            ContentValues cv = getContValues(tmp);
            loader.update(dbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, cv, dbHelper.UID + "=" + cv.getAsInteger("_id"), null);   
        //  db.UpdateItem(db.getWritableDatabase(), tmp);
        //  getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, mCallbacks);
        }
    });


    final ImageView fav_img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    if (fav_img != null)
    {
        if (tmp.getIsFav() != 0) {
            fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
        }
        else fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfav);
    }

    fav_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (tmp.getIsFav() == 1)
            {
                tmp.setIsFav(0);
                fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfav);
            }
            else 
            {
                tmp.setIsFav(1);
                fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
            }
            Log.d("fav:", Integer.toString(tmp.getIsFav()) + " id: " + Integer.toString(tmp.getGuid()));
        //  db.UpdateItem(db.getWritableDatabase(), tmp);
        //  getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, mCallbacks);
            //Working wrong!
            ContentValues cv = getContValues(tmp);
            loader.update(dbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, cv, dbHelper.UID + "=" + cv.getAsInteger("_id"), null);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
    if (tmp.getIsRead() != 0)
        lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    else lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}

private ContentValues getContValues(News tmp)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("_id", tmp.getGuid());
    cv.put("title", tmp.getName());
    cv.put("pubdate", tmp.getPubdate());
    cv.put("description", tmp.getDescr());
    cv.put("isRead", tmp.getIsRead());
    cv.put("isFav", tmp.getIsFav());
    return cv;
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return v;
}

private String convertLongToDate(long value)
{
    Locale l = new Locale("ru");
    //if (l.getCountry())
    Date d = new Date(value);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d M", l);
    return new String(df.format(d));                
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just do this adjustments:

```
final ImageView fav_img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Boolean is_favourite = false;
    if (fav_img != null)
    {
        if (tmp.getIsFav() != 0) {
            fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
        }
        else fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfav);
    }

    fav_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (is_favourite) // if your row is already favourite
            {
               is_favourite=false;
                fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfav);
            }
            else 
            {
                is_favourite= true;
                fav_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
            }
            //Log.d("fav:", Integer.toString(tmp.getIsFav()) + " id: " + Integer.toString(tmp.getGuid()));
        //  db.UpdateItem(db.getWritableDatabase(), tmp);
        //  getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, mCallbacks);
            //Working wrong!
            ContentValues cv = getContValues(tmp);
            loader.update(dbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, cv, dbHelper.UID + "=" + cv.getAsInteger("_id"), null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So, what about the TextView in row? Same trouble with it.

Comment: I did some adjustments to your code. When you click on your image it changes the boolean value `is_favourite`. I think that is all you need. Let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: Thats wrong code adjustments, coz i need to change data in db too(for saving state), but ur adjusts dont do this). Changing to ImageButton is not help too. It seems that the cursor taking wrong position, idk how and why.

Comment: @Dyna How are you using `is_favourite` without it being `final`?